# .fadeTo not working on my code, but works fine with same code on w3School. Why?

Tags: jquery, mobile, fadeto

So basically this works on w3School but not in my live environment. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
        <title>Vecta Corp. Mobile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
          <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#5").click(function(){
            $("#yourview").fadeTo(1000, 0.05);
        });
    });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <section data-role="content">

            <h2>Dr. Tint SolarPill Tint</h2>
            <h3>See how SolarPill looks from inside your tinted car</h3>

            <p><img alt="" src="images/tintshade.png" id="yourview" style="width:347px;"></p>
<p style="width:350px;">
<input id="5" value="5%"  style="font-size:12px;width: 36px;margin-left: 18px;" type="button">

</p>


        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the : [w3school link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_fadeto) and paste this code into it and try for yourself:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#5").click(function(){
        $("#yourview").fadeTo(1000, 0.4);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><img alt="" src="http://www.mobile-tinting.com/img.png" id="yourview" style="width:347px;"></p>

<input id="5" value="5%" style="font-size:12px;width: 36px;margin-left: 18px;" type="button">
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a conflict with jquery mobile as that is literally the only difference between the two codes. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does your Developer Console tell? btw, try a better tutorial website.

Comment: Works well for me.. Check your browser `console`..

Comment: I checked my console and it shows up fine, but for some weird reason it just doesn't work. Does my code work fine for you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a few examples on this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nikkow/pen/WwqMPP). It seems a common problem that button inputs are unclickable (it seems to be due to jQuery Mobile). You can try a few other way to achieve what's you are trying to do:

1. Use a `<button>` tag instead
2. Use a `<a>` tag, setting the `data-role` attribute to `button` so it adopts the button style.

Comment: Yes. This was it! Thanks. Changed to buttons and its working now. Jquery mobile seems to be buggy.